# How to add an arrow in top of the other in tikz-cd?

Tags: tikz-cd

I wanted it to look like `\rightlefttarrows` (as in one arrow in top of the other)

```
 \begin{tikzcd}
 X \ar{r} & \ar[l] B
 \end{tikzcd}
```

The above code does not have that effect and instead fuses both arrows.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community  What is not clear about my question? I want an arrow to be on the top of the other, as in the \rightleftarrows symbol, and the code i provided does not do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using the `shift left` key (or `shift right` in the second example). Both produce the same output:

[image]

The direction of the shift is from the perspective of "walking along the arrow". So if the arrow is drawn from `B` to `X`, the left side is below. But if the arrow is drawn from `X` to `B`, then left is above, even if the arrow is pointing "backwards". You can adjust the spacing between the arrows to your liking.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
X \arrow[r, shift left=2pt] &  B \arrow[l, shift left=2pt]
\end{tikzcd}

\begin{tikzcd}
X \arrow[r, shift left=2pt] \arrow[r, <-, shift right=2pt]&  B 
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```